# javascript - center div (position:absolute) vertically and horizontally to screen view

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to make a usercript that overlays text boxes over images: It uses a draggable menu using interactjs with fixed position. The menu has a button and I need it to create a div of 20px*60px and show it at the center of the screen view (so not to scroll to the bottom of the page and drag it from there). I can do it (somewhat) by using:

```
var div = document.getElementById("inserted_div_2");
div.style.position = 'fixed';
div.style.top = '50%'; //relative to screen
div.style.left = '50%';
```

From there I can drag/resize it to where I want over the image (also using interactjs) but then, how can I change it to position:absolute so it scrolls with the content keeping the same position over the images (eg: in the top left corner of img2)? something like:

```
var posX = div.getPosX(); //relative to page; in %, px or em
var posY = div.getPosY();
// when I change it from fixed to absolute the div goes back to the bottom of the page
div.style.position = 'absolute';
div.style.left = posX;
div.style.top = posY;
```

The HTML structure looks something like this:

```
<body>
    ...
    <div id="content">
        ...
        <img src="/img1.jpg"> // size and number of imgs is variable.
        <img src="/img2.jpg"> // are in a strip format.
        <img src="/img3.jpg">
        ...
    </div>
    ...
    <div id="overlays">

         //eg: div1 was dragged from the center of screen 
         //into in between img1 and img2
         <div id="inserted_div_1">Text</div>

         //now I need to do the same for div2, 
         //dragging it to the top left corner of img2
         <div id="inserted_div_2">Text</div>

    </div>
</body>
```

I would prefer not using jQuery or another library, but if it is too difficult then I will use it.
Thanks!

Comment: The way you describe it, it sounds like you actually _want_ it to scroll with the content. What is it now?

Comment: @DanMan yeah you're right. I'm sorry english isn't my main language, but I will edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `offsetTop` and `offsetLeft` to get the element's position (in px) relative to the page.

```
var posX = div.offsetLeft;
var posY = div.offsetTop;
div.style.position = 'absolute';
div.style.left = posX;
div.style.top = posY;
```

**UPDATE**

The values returned by `offsetTop` and `offsetLeft` do not include the `transform:translate` styles applied. I created a [test case](http://jsfiddle.net/u3ay74bs/) - its not dragable but it shows you how to calculate the relative positions by adding the `offset` and the `translate` values:

```
var div = document.getElementById("inserted_div_2");
var content = document.getElementById("content");

function testpos(){
    var ol = div.offsetLeft,
        ot = div.offsetTop,
        cs = window.getComputedStyle(div, null),
        tr = cs.getPropertyValue("-webkit-transform") ||
             cs.getPropertyValue("-moz-transform") ||
             cs.getPropertyValue("-ms-transform") ||
             cs.getPropertyValue("-o-transform") ||
             cs.getPropertyValue("transform") ||
             false;
        //outputs something like 'matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 80, 90)'
        var values = tr.replace(/[^0-9\.\,]/g,'').split(','),//split into array
            tx = values[4] || 0,//take the x value (else 0)
            ty = values[5] || 0;//take the y value (else 0)       
    //
    content.innerHTML+=("<hr />position: "+div.style.position+"<br />");
    content.innerHTML+=("offsetLeft:"+ol+", offsetTop:"+ot+"<br />");
    content.innerHTML+=("translate-x:"+tx+", translate-y:"+ty+"<br />");
    //so the actual position is the offset + the translate ==
    var x = parseInt(ol) + parseInt(tx),
        y = parseInt(ot) + parseInt(ty);
    content.innerHTML+=("x:"+x+" y:"+y+"<br />");
}

/* TEST */
//1 set to fixed
div.style.position = 'fixed';
testpos();//test position
//2 move using transfor:translate
div.style.transform = 'translate(80px,90px)';
testpos();//test position (note the offset does not include the transform)
/3 set to absolute and get the position
div.style.position = 'absolute';
testpos();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u3ay74bs/

Comment: tried using `offsetLeft` but I think because I am dragging using css translate the values don't change. If I use     `getBoundingClientRect` the values only change when dragging (relative to screen), not when scrolling (relative to page).

Comment: You can get the `transform:translate` value and add it to the `offsets`. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use css for center div vertically and horizontally

for example

```
#content{
     position:absolute;
     width:100px;
     height:100px;
     left:50%;
     top:50%;
     margin-left:-50px; /*half width*/
     margin-top:-50px; /*half height*/
}

<div id='content'>
     ...
</div>
```

if width equal 100px margin-left equal -50px
if width equal 200px margin-left equal -100px
and so on

margin-left half width
and
margin-top half height